# JavaScript image pre-loading not working

Tags: javascript, image, background, preloading

I cannot make this code work for me. I would like to pre-load a handful of large images that will be swapped with each other for the current page's background on a regular timer.

```
var images = new Array()
for (i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
    images[i] = new Image();
    images[i].src = "http://imagesource_" + i + ").jpg";
}

setInterval(function () {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage="url('" + images[11].src + "')";
}, 15000);
```

Comment: Are you sure the `src` URL is correct? What kind of errors do you get?

Answer (score 0):

You are not preloading anything now. You are just loading a bunch of url's in an array.

Have a look at: http://fragged.org/preloading-images-using-javascript-the-right-way-and-without-frameworks_744.html